# Non-interactive logon to RabbitMQ with Azure AD Oauth

Tags: powershell, oauth, rabbitmq

Recently we setup OAuth authorization in Azure AD for RabbitMQ instance based on this guide https://www.rabbitmq.com/oauth2-examples-azure.html.

Interactive authorization works fine for AD users (which have App Registration roles assigned) but now we need to be able to authorize to rabbitmq with powershell using oauth and that is where we got stuck.

If we go through interactive authorization and get the token from Google Chrome Dev Tools we can use this token to authorize, but we can't get this token with powershell.

Our rabbitmq.conf looks like this:

```
listeners.ssl.default = 5671
ssl_options.cacertfile = <Cert Path>
ssl_options.certfile = <Cert Path>
ssl_options.keyfile = <Cert Path>
ssl_options.password = <password>
management.ssl.port       = 15671
management.ssl.cacertfile = <Cert Path>
management.ssl.certfile   = <Cert Path>
management.ssl.keyfile    = <Cert Path>
management.ssl.password = <Password>
log.file.level = debug
auth_backends.1 = rabbit_auth_backend_oauth2
auth_backends.2 = internal
auth_oauth2.https.peer_verification = verify_none
auth_oauth2.resource_server_id = <AppRegistrationID>
auth_oauth2.jwks_url = https://login.microsoftonline.com/<TenantID>/discovery/v2.0/keys
auth_oauth2.additional_scopes_key = roles
auth_oauth2.https.cacertfile = <Cert Path>
management.oauth_enabled = true  
management.oauth_client_id = <AppRegistrationID>
management.oauth_provider_url = https://login.microsoftonline.com/<TenantID>
```

we tried to use PowerShell script like this to get the token:

```
$tokenParams = @{
    "grant_type"="client_credentials"
    "scope"="api://<AppRegistrationID>/access-api"
    "client_id"=$clientID
    "client_secret"=$clientSecret
    "redirect_uri"="https://<rabbitserver>:15671/js/oidc-oauth/login-callback.html"
}
$tokenResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $tokenEndpoint -Method POST -ContentType "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -Body $tokenParams
$accessToken = $tokenResponse.access_token
```

Then use this token to authorize:

```
$headers = @{
    "Authorization" = "Bearer $accessToken"
}
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://<rabbitserver>:15671/api/whoami" -Method GET -Headers $headers
```

But it returns "Not Authorized" which makes sense as token that we get via powershell does not contain roles and we can't make it accept AD users credentials, it works only with client secret. And it also works if we use token from browsers dev tools after interactive logon.

We suspect that user authorization flow with role claims may not work for non-interactive logon, but we could not find any documentation on alternative configuration for rabbitmq/azure ad oauth.
Is there any way to non-interactively get the token with powershell which can be then used to authenticate to RabbitMQ?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. We tried to use second app registration (client) with api permissions to the first one (server), assuming that requesting clients token will give us role claims for server's app registration. And it is true. The issue was that when we tried this approach we used client's client id in both token request and rabbitmq.conf, while actually we should use server's app registration id in rabbitmq.conf and ,client's id in powershell token request. Now we can both logon interactively and request token with powershell which can access the api.